# Selenium-cannot find input bar and type into into it in python

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping

> ERROR MESSAGE:   element = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,
> 'input#IDAPAMWB') selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException:
> Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css
> selector","selector":"input#IDAPAMWB"}   (Session info:
> chrome=95.0.4638.54)

I keep getting this error though I added a sleep command from other solutions for the page and load dynamically with python but still, it cannot find it?. Here a snippet of my code

```
if(selection == 1):
        target=driver.find_element("xpath","/html/body/main/article/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/a")
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", target)
        time.sleep(5)
        element = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'input#IDAPAMWB')
        element.send_keys("Hey Josh")
        element.submit()
```

And this is the imported library and files

```
import time
from openpyxl import workbook, load_workbook
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

<input id="IDAPIBTB" class="plxsty_pid" size="80" value="RL-????" defaultvalue="" onkeyup="OnPIDInputChange( event );" style="visibility: visible;">
https://www.mtecorp.com/click-find/ 
then click on any hyperlinks to take you to the website.
```

Here is what the element looks like from the webpage

```
<td align="left">
<input id="IDAPA0M" class="plxsty_pid" size="80" value="RL-OO" defaultvalue="" onkeyup="OnPIDInputChange( event );" style="visibility: visible;">
</td>
```

Comment: Can you share a link to that page and explain what element are you trying to click there?

Comment: This is wrong `target=driver.find_element("xpath","/html/body/main/article/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/a")` xpath is not string, this should have given compile time error. try this instead `target=driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/main/article/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/a")`

Comment: Also, please check if element is in iframe or put a delay before interacting with it. Please share more relevant HTML code or page URL if possible.

Comment: Please check in the dev tools (Google chrome) if we have unique entry in HTML DOM or not. Steps to check: Press F12 in Chrome -> go to element section -> do a CTRL  + F -> then paste the id and see, if your desired element is getting highlighted with 1/1 matching node.

Comment: Yes, for Link for the website I'm trying to pull is this http://prod.symx.com/MTECorp/config.asp?cmd=edit&CID=449510ADD9104131B0234CF804133F48 it have been able to move a main page of this company to this page just haven't be able to get it to click on this element

Comment: for the question on the desired element is getting highlighted with 1/1 matching mode I am not too familiar with HTML and selenium at all. But I can share the HTML code of the page with the element inside <input id="IDAPA4M" class="plxsty_pid" size="80" value="RL-????" defaultvalue="" onkeyup="OnPIDInputChange( event );" style="visibility: visible;">